# android ripple not working on RecyclerView items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, ripple

I have a RecyclerView with four items and applied ripple effect to the background of the RecyclerView item layout.When I click the item, ripple is not displaying.

categories.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/category"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/ripple_effect_2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
   >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:id="@+id/offimg"
    android:tint="#50000000"
    android:src="@drawable/electronics"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hotels"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

ripple_effect_2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="#ffffff"
    >
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask"
        android:drawable="@color/semiTransparentBlack">

    </item>
</ripple>
```

Comment: How are you detecting the click event? are you using a Gesture Detector?

Comment: In the recycler adapter using onclicklistener on the view

Comment: take a read of this article, it'll advise on ways to avoid this. http://www.littlerobots.nl/blog/Handle-Android-RecyclerView-Clicks/

Answer (score 0):

if you use ConstraintLayout try this

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

else

```
 android:clickable="true"
 android:focusable="true"
 android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```